# Efficient substring matching in perl

Tags: perl, string, string-matching, substring, bioperl

I am looking for an efficient solution to do find the longest possible substring in a string tolerating *n* mismatches in the main string

Eg:
Main String

1. AGACGTAC**TACTCTACT**AGATGCA*TACTCTAC*
2. AGACGTAC**TACTCTACT**AGATGCA*TACTCTAC*
3. AGACGTAC**TACTCTACA**AGATGCA*TACTCTAC*
4. AGACGTAC**TACTTTACA**AGATGCA*TACTCTAC*

Search String:

1. TACTCTACT  : this should be considered a match to all of the above main strings.

Also I there could be the case where part of the substring is at the end of main string and I would like to pick that up also.

I would appreciate if you could give some pointers.

PS: I will have one search string and about 100  million main strings to search the substring for.

Thanks!
-Abhi

Comment: Questions.  1) Your numbers in "Main String" - are those separate lines in one "Main String", or four separate "Main String"s (I assume the latter, but want to confirm)?  2) Can you explain why that search string would be considered a match for #3 and #4?  The first two clearly match, but it's not clear to me why the last two do, and that sounds like it may be a crucial detail to understand.  3) Can you explain what you mean that part of the substring may be at the end of the main string?

Comment: You mention "longest", but your example doesn't provide any clue as to what you mean by longest. Do you mean with the fewest mismatch?

Comment: @Brian Gerard: 1) Those are 4 of the million main strings. 2) Because he tolerates mismatches. #3: A for T, #4, T for C, A for T. 3) "...TACT" should end-of-line-match search string TACTCTACT, because it might be followed by "CTACT".

Comment: @Brian : 1.) I showed 4 different types of main strings for example purpose. 2.) I am allowing for n mismatches. In this case n = 1,2 etc. 3.) the search string could be partially contained in the main string and we want to match that partial case also. Thanks for your questions

Comment: @ikegami : By longest I mean the literally the "longest" and best possible match ( least mismatches). In way this could be misleading and thanks for asking.  So longest might not be the right word. What I meant was if the substring is partially contained at the end of main string I would like to pick that case and not ingore it. I hope this makes it a bit more clearer.

Comment: `TACTCTAC*` is a better match than `TACTTTACA` in your fourth example

Comment: @ikegami : thanks for your help so far. I have another follow up question. Previously I had one query string compared to millions of search string one at a time for a substring occurence. Now if I want to increase my search space to include multiple query strings, I can either run the same logic again  but can I use other data structures which can build something like a suffix tree for query strings and use that for searching substring in the search string ?? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

sub match {
   my ($s, $t, $max_x) = @_;

   my $m = my @s = unpack('(a)*', $s);
   my $n = my @t = unpack('(a)*', $t);

   my @length_at_k     = ( 0 ) x ($m+$n);
   my @mismatches_at_k = ( 0 ) x ($m+$n);
   my $offset = $m;

   my $best_length = 0;
   my @solutions;
   for my $i (0..$m-1) {
      --$offset;

      for my $j (0..$n-1) {
         my $k = $j + $offset;

         if ($s[$i] eq $t[$j]) {
            ++$length_at_k[$k];
         }
         elsif ($length_at_k[$k] > 0 && $mismatches_at_k[$k] < $max_x) {
            ++$length_at_k[$k];
            ++$mismatches_at_k[$k];
         }
         else {
            $length_at_k[$k] = 0;
            $mismatches_at_k[$k] = 0;
         }

         my $length = $length_at_k[$k] + $max_x - $mismatches_at_k[$k];
         $length = $i+1 if $length > $i+1;

         if ($length >= $best_length) {
            if ($length > $best_length) {
               $best_length = $length;
               @solutions = ();
            }

            push @solutions, $i-$length+1;
         }
      }
   }

   return map { substr($s, $_, $best_length) } @solutions;
}

say for match('AABBCC', 'DDBBEE', 2);
```

Output:

```
AABB
ABBC
BBCC
```

Comment: you code works absolutely fine. Just wanted to get some idea if the number of sequences that I am checking in a certain amount time sounds feasible or is there a way to scale it up.  I am searching for a 36 alphabets substring (with upto 5 mismatches) in 90 million 100 alphabets long search sequences. It is taking me about 13 hours to do this search. Does this sounds like normal based on your experience. I haven't time/memory profiled my code. Thanks!

Comment: @Abhi, I'm no expert in algorithms, but I took every shortcut I could think of. You could make it an order or two faster by implementing it in C.

Comment: @Mariya, It's based on a "dynamic programming" solution to the Longest Common Substring problem. See an explanation of what it's based on [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem#Dynamic_programming).

Answer (score 11):

I'm not certain that this is what you're after but BioPerl has an approximate-grep tool called [`Bio::Grep::Backend::Agrep`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Bio%3a%3aGrep%3a%3aBackend%3a%3aAgrep):

> Bio::Grep::Backend::Agrep searches for a query with agrep

And [`agrep`](http://www.tgries.de/agrep/) is "approximate grep". AFAIK, this builds a database and then uses that database to make your searches faster so this sounds like what you're after.

Looks like you're working with DNA sequences so you probably have BioPerl already installed.

You could also try using [`String::Approx`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?String%3a%3aApprox) directly:

> Perl extension for approximate matching (fuzzy matching)

I suspect that `Bio::Grep::Backend::Agrep` will be faster and a better match for your task though.

Comment: I will try this and let you guys know it that works and is efficient.